# stream_socket_client() not working and ignoring timeout

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to execute a `stream_socket_client()` from PHP to receive data from a Windows. Here's my environments:

---

**Localhost**: Windows 8 and PHP 5.3.8. *THE SCRIPT WORKS PERFECT AND TAKES 25 SECONDS.*
**Windows Telnet**: From the Windows Telnet client, it works just fine. I can receive data from the server.
**External Server**: centOS with PHP 5.3.3. THE SCRIPT TAKES UP TO 5 MINUTES TO TIMEOUT.
**Internal Server**: centOS with PHP 5.3.3. THE SCRIPT NEVER TIMES OUT.

*Note:* for the Internal Server to work, the `$address` variable is changed to `192.168.0.7`.

My question is more about what should I be looking for? Should I be worried about 5.3.3 Vs 5.3.8? Or is there something on Linux that I must focus on to make this work?

- I know is not a firewall problem, since from my machine works (located outside) and both, a external server and the internal server isn't working.
- I know the `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1.

ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);

```
$address = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = 'tcp://' . $address . ':6000';
$fp = stream_socket_client($portao, $errno, $errstr, 10);    
if (!$fp) {
    echo ("$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");
    exit;    
} else {
    $out = 'open 192.168.0.22' . PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($fp, $out);

    $output = 'Nothing here.';

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $output = stream_get_contents($fp);
    }


    fclose($fp);    
    echo $output;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the line `$out = 'open 192.168.0.22' . PHP_EOL;` more specifically `PHP_EOL` . Since the server target is running Windows, it expects `\r\n` as a character return. My computer (localhost) is running Windows, which makes `PHP_EOL = \r\n`, but once I deployed the application on a Linux server, the `PHP_EOL` there is set to `\n`. My problem was solved with the following line:

```
$out = 'open 192.168.0.22' . "\r\n";
```

*Note:* the character `\r\n` must be wrapped in double quotes mark (`""`) for it to work.